# Authentication Against Company Django Rest OAuth2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have one `Company` Model and `User` Model. I want to create `client_id` and `client_secret` against company name. And when user accessing API `Username` and `Password` will be sended along with Companies `client_id` and `client_secret`. When user is authenticated then api will be visible. Which Grant Type can i use, How can i differentiate users who is accessing api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make custom `Authentication` class with `django-rest-framework`. See [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication).

For example, you can set `is_client_checked` `True` in `request` object if requester has correct `client_id` and `client_secret`. So you can get that value in your `view`